# Identifying Specific Characters from Text Input

Tags: php

**Original title**:
*to read and count the occurrence of only limited characters of A,G,C,T present in the input text file, for example only 100 out of 500 and draw a thin verticular rectangle barcode images using gd*

It read and counts only first 10 characters and draw a barcode image, instead of specified 100 characters.

```
<?php
$file="co3.txt";
$handle=fopen($file, 'r');

$A=0;
$G=0;
$C=0;
$T=0;

$img = imagecreate(850,80);
$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255,255,255);
$green=imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 128, 0);
$black=imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
$red=imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0);
$blue=imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 255);

$x1=40;
$y1=40;
$x2=43;
$y2=80;

$contents = '';

#while(( ($contents=fread( $handle, 100)) !='')) {
while(( ($contents=fread($handle, 100)) )) {
for ($i=0; $i<=100; $i++)

{

  if($contents[$i] == 'A')
{

$A++;
imagefilledrectangle($img, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $green);
$x1 = $x1+6;
$x2 = $x2+6;

}

else
if($contents[$i] == 'G')

{

$G++;
imagefilledrectangle($img, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $black);
$x1 = $x1+6;
$x2 = $x2+6;

}

else
if($contents[$i] == 'C')

{

$C++;
imagefilledrectangle($img, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $blue);
$x1 = $x1+6;
$x2 = $x2+6;

}

else
if($contents[$i] == 'T')

{

$T++;
imagefilledrectangle($img, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $red);
$x1 = $x1+6;
$x2 = $x2+6;

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
}

}

}

?>
```

Comment: @s.mahalingam: yep and what is the question ?

Comment: the requirement is to read & count only 100 characters so as to draw and output image of barcode instead of reading more than 100 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you only not so much the first 10 letters, but up to the point when a T is found.  Then, the misplaced snippet producing the image ouptut this image.  The loop may continue up to 100, producing possibly a few more images (with each new T), but I don't know PHP behavior in such cases, since some of the HTTP response is readily written...

Alternatively you may be seeing the *last* of these images.  At any rate, by fixing the misplaced

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

things should start to look more as expected.